# Question title placeholder is partially obscured in the iOS app

Tags: bug, ios-app

After upgrading to iOS 11 I noticed that question title placeholder is partially obscured:

> [image: title]

- App Version: 1.7.0.1
- Device: Unknown (iPad7,3)
- OS Version: Version 11.0 (Build 15A372)